# How to pass arguments to mapDispatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I use React-Redux in my application. I wrote the mapDispatch function in which I want to pass arguments

Now, when clicking, an object is displayed in the console in which authorId: undefined, title: undefined. How can you pass arguments to mapDispatch()?

```js
const mapDispatch = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    addNewPost: () => dispatch(addNewPost(ownProps.authorId, ownProps.title)),
  };
};

export class PostForm extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    selectedAuthor: null,
    authors: this.props.authors,
  };

  onSelectedAuthorChanged = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ selectedAuthor: value || null });
  };

  onPostTitleChanged = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ title: value });
  };

  onAddNewPostClicked = () => {
    if (this.state.title !== null && this.state.selectedAuthor !== null) {
      console.log(
        this.props.addNewPost(this.state.selectedAuthor, this.state.title)
      );
      this.setState({ title: "" });
    } else {
      return;
    }
    ...
}

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(PostForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ownProps` args passed to `mapDispatchToProps` (in your case `mapDispatch` ) function in `Redux-connect` contains the props that being passed when the component is invoked.

Using `<PostForm authorId="1" title="test" />` should get you the desired results.